# Getting selections from a list object

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table inside of appmaker that I've added checkboxes to like so:

[image: app screenshot showing checkbox in list]

I'd like to get a list of the emails from entires that the user checks. At this point I'm not even able to access the status of a single checkbox. This is the current code snippet I tried adding to a button:

`console.log(widget.parent.parent.parent.children.Panel1.children.Table3Panel.children.Table3.children.Table3Body.children.Table3Row.children.UserSelectionCheckbox.value);`

I get the error:

`Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
at Home.Panel1.OuSelectPanel1.Button6.onClick:1:133`

I was able to use the autofill to write this entire statement, why can't it find the child object? Is there any way to reference this list directly without going down the tree from the widget or the app root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of functionality the autofill (intellisense) will not work for you. You need to address the children differently when you try to get a collection of rows from a table. I would suggest code similar to this for your button onClick event:

```
var rows = widget.root.descendants.Table3Body.children._values;
var emails = [];
for (var i in rows) {
  var value = rows[i].children.Checkbox1.value;  
  if (value) {
    emails.push(rows[i].datasource.item.Email);
  }
}
console.log(emails);
```

Again the auto complete code feature simply won't work after you choose the _values, which will return all immediate children of your table body, which is what you want.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Can you help me understand why the autofill is showing things existing when they aren't?

Comment: @IanHyzy The code works in developer mode because your Table3Body.children.Table3Row actually exists, because there is only 1 child to Table3Body which is Table3Row. However in preview/deployment, your Table3Body actually has many children, and those children are actually named Table3Row$0, Table3Row$1 and so on for however many table rows you have. That is also why the autofill stops working when addressing all children rows, because the autofill does not know the name assigned to each table row.

Answer (score 0):

based on the 1:133 it seems to be saying that Table3Row has no children. I wonder if using widget.root.descendants.Table3Row might be a different way of doing it address the particular table.

Comment: That's a much faster way I didn't know existed, thanks. I tried `console.log(widget.root.descendants.Table3Body.children.Table3Row.children.UserSelectionCheckbox.value);` and it failed with a similar `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
at Home.Panel1.OuSelectPanel1.Button6.onClick:1:67
` error.

The table also doesn't have children by default but children are generated before this button is clicked.

Comment: Are you able to do root.descendants.UserSelectionCheckbox.value? I think root.descendants is a non-hierarchical list of everything on the page.

Comment: I was able to use Markus' answer above - I was unaware of how the descendants would appear once the page was rendered.